# datagridview binding to entity not updating database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am populating a grid from a entity object and it is displaying the data fine. When I make changes and save it back, nothing is updating.

Here is my code:

In my load event:

```
  var query = from c in _entities.PaymentTypes
              where c.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId
              select
                new DataBindingProjection
                  {
                    PaymentTypeId = c.PaymentTypeId,
                    CorporationId = c.CorporationId,
                    TokenId = c.TokenId,
                    IsActive = c.IsActive,
                    Description = c.Description,
                    CashChargeCodeType = c.CashChargeCodeType,
                    SortOrder = c.SortOrder,
                    ExcludeCreditCode = c.ExcludeCreditCodes,
                    IsUpdated = c.IsUpdated,
                    IsAdded = c.IsAdded,
                    ClearUpdatedAndAdded = c.ClearUpdateAndAdded
                  };
  dataGridView_PaymentTypes.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

My class:

```
private class DataBindingProjection
{
  public Guid PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
  public Guid CorporationId { get; set; }
  public Guid TokenId { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int CashChargeCodeType { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
  public int ExcludeCreditCode { get; set; }
  public bool IsUpdated { get; set; }
  public bool IsAdded { get; set; }
  public bool ClearUpdatedAndAdded { get; set; }
}
```

In the button to save the changes:

```
private void button_SaveChanges2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button_SaveChanges2.Enabled = false;
  _entities.SaveChanges();
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  button_SaveChanges2.Enabled = true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**In response to bmused:**

Defined at the class level:

```
private SuburbanPortalEntities _entities;
```

defined in my load:

```
  var bs = new BindingSource();
  _entities.PaymentTypes.Where(x => x.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId).Load;
  bs.DataSource = _entities.PaymentTypes.Local.ToBindingList();
  dataGridView_PaymentTypes.DataSource = bs;
```

It is showing that it cannot load symbol Load and Local:

[image]

Comment: Why are you projecting to another type that has the exact same properties of your entity?

Comment: testing, I've tried several different ideas and I ended up with this. Granted it's not needed but I left it.

Comment: should't `Load` be `Load()` ?

Comment: yes... but it wasn't finding load with or without them so the () doesn't matter if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two-way databinding with Winforms and Entity Framework can be achieved by creating an `IBindinglist` from the `DbContext` `Local` `ObservableCollection<T>` and setting it as the `DataSource` of a `BindingSource`.  Example:

```
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

context.MyEntities.Where(x=>x.SomeProperty == 2).Load(); 
bs.DataSource = context.MyEntities.Local.ToBindingList(); 
myDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get back sooner, I was sick. Anyhow, it says cannot resolve symbol Load or Local. I'll post my code up top for your review.

Comment: @ErocM what version of Entity Framework? The above should work for EF 4.1+ as it uses the `DbContext` API not the old `ObjectContext` API. Also check that you reference `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: v4.0.30319 where and how do you get 4.1+ ? I am using .net 4.0 full.

Comment: @ErocM You can get the latest version as a nuget package http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906

Comment: ok got ef 5.0 and was able to load the extention for Load but it's not finding Local. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ErocM You might be still using `ObjectContext` API

Answer (score 4):

You are change the properties of the projected copy of the entity, while entity itself stays unchanged. That is why save does not work - entity stays unchanged.

You need either bind entities itself as DataSource to grid, or update property of the corresponding entity when you updating property of projection instance.

Answer (score 2):

`.Load()` and `.Local` will be visible when use reference:

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the new DataBindingProjection() so we are assuming this is a class that is controlled by your context right?

Assuming that, what i see that is missing in your code is for you to pass the new instance of DataBindingProjection to your DbContext(if using 4.2+ or to the ObjectContext if using older versions, i would recommend migrating to 5.0)

You need to Attach() the created entities to the context before calling the SaveChanges(), i don't see this in your code.

The is the way for you to create new records to the database. If you want to change records that are at the database, you should not use the Linq approach where you create a new object, you should call the object itself, so it can have the EF proxies and be tracked by the ChangeTracker of EF.

For me it seems that you have a new class that is not tracked by EF.....

If you did something like this, then it should work (im assuming a property named Projection to be in your entities, just for an example) :

```
var query = from c in _entities.PaymentTypes
         where c.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId 
         select c.Projection;

dataGridView_PaymentTypes.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

If you dont have that then you should do something like this:

```
var query = from c in _entities.PaymentTypes
         where c.CorporationId == _currentcorp.CorporationId 
         new DataBindingProjection
              {
                PaymentTypeId = c.PaymentTypeId,
                CorporationId = c.CorporationId,
                TokenId = c.TokenId,
                IsActive = c.IsActive,
                Description = c.Description,
                CashChargeCodeType = c.CashChargeCodeType,
                SortOrder = c.SortOrder,
                ExcludeCreditCode = c.ExcludeCreditCodes,
                IsUpdated = c.IsUpdated,
                IsAdded = c.IsAdded,
                ClearUpdatedAndAdded = c.ClearUpdateAndAdded
              };

foreach(var item in query)
    (DbContext)YourInstanceOfContext.Set<DataBindingProjection>().Add(item);

dataGridView_PaymentTypes.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

After this you will be able to save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my post about binding a datagridView, the method works very well and its very helpfull: [Best approach to bind a datagridview to database entity/ies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117217/best-aproach-to-bind-a-datagridview-to-database-entity-ies)